# javascript runtime error with `rails s` command on remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vps

I just set up a VPS to prepare for launching a Rails app and, on the actual remote server, I created a new rails project to test things out, only doing `rails new blog -d postgresql`. I then tried to start the server using the `rails s` command and got the error below.

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anwalt/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anwalt/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anwalt/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anwalt/gems/uglifier-2.1.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anwalt/gems/uglifier-2.1.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/michael/blogy/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anwalt/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anwalt/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anwalt/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anwalt/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I installed `$ gem install execjs` but still get the same error (I think I have to require it somewhere). Anyways, my question is, why wouldn't the `rails s` command work on a VPS out of the box the way that it works on a local machine, and, if not using `rails s` command how am I supposed to start the application once I do launch my real app (rather than this dummy app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install `node.js` via `apt-get install nodejs` or `sudo apt-get install nodejs` if you are using debian\ubuntu.

Comment: ok, thanks, that works, the server started in development at `http://0.0.0.0:3000` but when I go to that address it just says 'Chrome could not connect.' When I enter the ip address instead, it's also the same.